# MVC 2 Antiforgerytoken session issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, antiforgerytoken, sessionend

I've implemented the antiforgerytoken in my MVC 2 app.
I have also added a **machine key** in the `web.config`.  When the session expires and I try and do a post it throws a `A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid` error.
It seems like the antiforgery token is expiring.

My question is

- Why is it throwing an error after session expiry?
- How long is the token valid for?

Answer (score 3):

I've never experienced such problem and I am pretty sure that the AntiForgeryToken do not expire but I was reading [here](http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2010/03/18/beware-upgrade-to-asp-net-mvc-2-0-with-care-if-you-use-antiforgerytoken/) and it seems that someone has had your problem.

I do not use the machine key. 
I simply do something like this:

```
<% using(Html.Form("UserProfile", "SubmitUpdate")) { %>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken("AF-MyApp-token") %>
    <!-- rest of form goes here -->
<% } %>
```

and server-side:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt="AF-MyApp-token")]
public ViewResult SubmitUpdate()
{
    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: It is very frustrating as there's not a whole lot you can mess up by implementing the antiforgery tokens in your app.  Am I right in thinking that you simply add the machinekey to your web.config and they will automatically use it?

Comment: @doogdeb: I've updated my answer. I had got inspiration from here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-%20aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: I've looked at that soluition before but I still had the same issue.  Also my app is going to be deployed in a web farm so that's why I went the machinekey route.

Comment: @doogdeb: As I said I haven't experienced anything like that. But, anyway, the article that jamescrowley has written (see the link in my answer) has got a solution for that.

Comment: Firefox says that the __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__ cookie expires at the end of the session. I tested this in MVC3, but assume this behaviour is consistent in MVC2.